# Clickhouse: how to find indexed field in clickhouse SQL?

Tags: sql, indexing, clickhouse

I have existing table in ClickHouse. I want to find which field is an index field. How do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;` to see the primary key (index) and other settings.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

`SELECT engine_full FROM system.tables;`